# Add text to user login page

Tags: theming, 8

I'm attempting to add text to user login page, with general info about accounts rather than only displaying the login form.

I have a page.html.twig template like so

```
{{ page.header }}
<h2>This is my page template</h2>
{{page.content}}
{{ page.footer }}
```

I then can create content in page--user--login.html.twig like so.

```
{{ page.header }}
<h2>This is my page template</h2>
<p>Enter your login information here</p>
{{page.content}}
{{ loginform }}
{{ page.footer }}
```

But is there anyway to just add text to the login form without recreating page.html.twig. Since it would just be a copy I'd rather consolidate everything so any change wouldn't have to be made to both. Is there a template I could use like node--user--login.html.twig. So that the content would use page.html.twig and use the page.content block?

I understand that you can make changes to the form using a theme_form_alter hook but I'm not sure how to add html to the form from there. I can only change things like placeholder text, and submit values.

Comment: Cant you use form alter and show the text

Comment: I am using form alter but I'm not sure how to add text using it. I know I can change things like the submit value, but I don't see a way to just add html.

Comment: @Matt please check the answer, how to do easily using hook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom block that appears only on /user.

After you create the custom block, configure it to appear in the content region. You could also need to set a condition for anonymous users.

Comment: You would also need to set a Condition for the anonymous user role.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this very simple way using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x).

Paste following code in your themename.theme file and clear the cache

```
function YourThemeName_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['newline'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t('<h2>Enter your login information here!</h2>'),
      '#weight' => -10,
    );
}
```

### Image output:

**Before:**

> [image]

**After:**

> [image]

This way you do not need to worry about anything, it will only show in Login page.

Answer (score 0):

Place this hook in your **.theme** file and replace **HOOK** with your theme name. You can change your heading and paragraph text accordingly.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form['#form_id'] == 'user_login_form') {
    $form['forgot'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#weight' => -10,
      '#markup' => '<h2>This is my page template</h2><p>Enter your login information here</p>', 
    );
    }
}
```

This hook will work properly. That is working fine for me.

Thank you